# Modernizr: Target IE for css3 transform

Tags: internet-explorer, css, transform, modernizr

I have used modernizr to detect the css3 properties that are unsupported by the browsers. For CSS3 transform property to rotate a div I have used the rule

```
.rotate-div{
    transform:rotate(-35deg);
}
```

Except IE other browser are working great with the property using vendor prefix. So as a fallback for IE I want to be the div to be straight. So if I want to target IE for css3 transform I have written as

```
.csstransforms .rotate-div{
     /*transform property*/
}
```

But modernizr targets Firefox and chrome also for css transforms. Any Idea to target only ie using modernizr.

Comment: -ms-transform:rotate(-35deg) , for IE9 and above ...

Comment: But I'm using prefix free jquery to take care of the vendor prefixes.

Comment: Modernizr `detects the availability of native implementations for next-generation web technologies`. It cannot target IE or any other browser. You should use use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to target IE.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 uses the `-ms` prefix and IE10 uses the non-prefixed version

[image: CanIUse]

Unfortunately Prefix Free isn't adding the -ms prefix or keeping the unprefixed version

[image: PrefixFree]

What you need is something like

```
.rotate-div {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-35deg);
    transform: rotate(-35deg);
}
```

This issue is mentioned in the [FAQ](https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/#faq) and in the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree/issues/16#issuecomment-2428237). Based on that feedback, it recommends doing something like the following...

```
.rotate-div {
    transform:rotate(-35deg);
}
.-webkit- .rotate-div {
    transform: rotate(-35deg) rotateX(0);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your detailed reply Elijah. I have found the mistake which was mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it's my mistake that I have to add the class name `.no-csstransforms` instead of `.csstransforms` before the unsupported properties classes. Its working now.